# npm nodejs vue/cli problem can't run 'vue ui'

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm

I am just trying to install the tool chain for Vue on a new Win10pro machine and stuck several times with different errors. However they all look like having the same root cause.

When I run `vue ui` the following error appears:

```
    @vue/cli 4.5.15
PS C:\Users\ralph\AppData\Roaming\npm> vue ui
  Starting GUI...
  Ready on http://localhost:8000
node:events:368
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:282:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:477:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:288:12)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:477:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn cmd',
  path: 'cmd',
  spawnargs: [ '/c', 'start', '""', '/b', 'http://localhost:8000' ]
}
```

I have set the run script policy of Windows to

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope LocalMachine
```

I understood that this allows any script from the local machine is allowed to run.

I find it suspicious that the nodejs install using the official installer msi installs with this bunch of warnings

```
PS C:\Users\ralph\AppData\Roaming\npm> npm i -g @vue/cli
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated apollo-tracing@0.15.0: The `apollo-tracing` package is no longer part of Apollo Server 3. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/migration/#tracing for details
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated graphql-extensions@0.15.0: The `graphql-extensions` API has been removed from Apollo Server 3. Use the plugin API instead: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/integrations/plugins/
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
npm WARN deprecated apollo-cache-control@0.14.0: The functionality provided by the `apollo-cache-control` package is built in to `apollo-server-core` starting with Apollo Server 3. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/migration/#cachecontrol for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
npm WARN deprecated graphql-tools@4.0.8: This package has been deprecated and now it only exports makeExecutableSchema.\nAnd it will no longer receive updates.\nWe recommend you to migrate to scoped packages such as @graphql-tools/schema, @graphql-tools/utils and etc.\nCheck out https://www.graphql-tools.com to learn what package you should use instead

added 941 packages, and audited 942 packages in 2m

67 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

11 vulnerabilities (4 moderate, 7 high)

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

any suggestion? I reinstalled everything already 5 times and followed all other recommendations I could find.

best wishes

Comment: Try to check if port 8000 is already busy in the OS.

Comment: the errno code -4058 indicates a problem with file access not at all a port issue, but thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause, very simple at the end.
the global path to \system32 was missing

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).